ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\razsh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-68pq_2jm
I got the following error: ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\razsh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-68pq_2jm
When i attempted to install XrayPhysics (from https://github.com/kylechampley/XrayPhysics) using the commands:
cd XrayPhysics
pip install .
After looking at answers to similar problems, i attempted to update setuptools, wheel, pip and numpy, clear my cache using 'pip cache purge' and uninstall then reinstall my python enviroment (anaconda), none of which had worked.
